# SQL Server schema-owner permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

if i do:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [test] AUTHORIZATION [testuser]
```

`testuser` doesn't seem to have any permissions on the schema, is this correct? I thought as the principal that owns the schema, you had full control over it?

What permission do i need to grant `testuser` so that it has full control over the `test` schema only?

**Edit:** by "full control" i mean the ability to CRUD tables, views, sprocs etc

**Edit:** here is my full code:

```
CREATE DATABASE [testdb]
Go
USE [testdb]

CREATE LOGIN [andrewbdesktop\testuser] FROM WINDOWS
Go

CREATE USER [andrewbdesktop\testuser] FROM LOGIN [andrewbdesktop\testuser]
Go

CREATE SCHEMA [test]
    AUTHORIZATION [andrewbdesktop\testuser]
Go

ALTER USER [andrewbdesktop\testuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [test]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

By default the schema owner **can**

- Grant permissions on any objects within the schema
- Drop the schema if it is empty
- Drop any object in the schema

By default the schema owner **cannot**

- Create objects in the schema. DDL events are not scoped at the schema level, they are scoped at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that with your statement, you're making that user the owner of the schema, so it should already have full control over the objects in that schema by default.

If you want more fine-grained control you can do statements like:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::test TO testuser
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::test TO testuser
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::test TO testuser
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::test TO testuser
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::test TO testuser
```

Comment: Thats what i thought, if i do `create table [test].[newtable] (id int)` i get: `CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'test'`

Comment: You also have to be a valid user in the database, and you have to explicitly not be denied access to create a table in that schema.

Comment: hmm ive added all my code to the question, does this look like it would be causing me access denied? Thanks

Comment: No, your code looks good to me.  I even tested it out on my box.  Can you post your exact error message?

Comment: i run that code as a dbo, then log onto sqlserver using windows authentication as testuser, if i try and create a table i get: `CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'testdb'.`